# inputText enter causes page refresh

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have several `inputText` boxes on a page with associated edit/submit buttons (which work).  I want to make it so that when the user presses enter from inside the `inputText` box, the form is submitted.  For one of my forms, it works, for the other, it doesn't.  Here's the one that doesn't work:

```
<h:form>
<iframe src="#{appInfo.documentation}"/>
<h:commandButton value="Edit" >
    <f:ajax listener="#{appInfo.editDoc}" render="@form"/>
</h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton value="Save" >
    <f:ajax listener="#{appInfo.saveDoc}" render="@form"/>
</h:commandButton>
<h:inputText value="#{appInfo.documentation}" > 
<!-- pressing enter causes page refresh -->
  <f:ajax/>
</h:inputText>
</h:form>
```

And the one that does:

```
<h:form>
  <h:dataTable id="table" value="#{appInfo.model.apps}" var="a">
    <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">URL</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{a.url}"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{a.url}">
    <!-- pressing enter does NOT causes page refresh -->
      <f:ajax/>
    </h:inputText>
    </h:column>
  </h:dataTable>
    ... command buttons
</h:form>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try to see how that iframe affect your page behaviour and check broeser console for errors

Comment: I just removed the iframe and got the same behavior.

Comment: check if you have nested forms (`h:form` inside another `h:form`)

Comment: What's the point of having that empty `f:ajax` tag inside of your `h:inputText`?

Comment: Hey @taylordurden, could the answer below help you?

Comment: Sorry, no that didn't solve my problem.  I'm still not sure what's causing it.  If I find a solution, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing "Enter" in an input field fires the same behaviour like **clicking** the **first `button`** of that form. In your second example there is no button at all. As soon as you add e.g. a `commandButton` there (like in the first example), the enter will be executed like expected.